# What is the Stirling formula for x(x+1)(x+2)...(x+n-1)?

Tags: tag-removed, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, analytic-number-theory

Let x be a complex number.

What is the Stirling formula for x(x+1)(x+2)...(x+n-1) when n goes to infinity?

Comment: I may be missing something, but how about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation#Stirling.27s_formula_for_the_Gamma_function

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like you want a formula for the asymptotics of the Pochhammer symbol $(x)_n$ as $n \to \infty$.  One such formula is provided about halfway down [Wolfram's page](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Pochhammer/introductions/FactorialBinomials/ShowAll.html):

$$(x)_n \sim \frac{2\pi}{\Gamma(x)} e^{-n}n^{x+n-\frac12}(1+O(\frac1n)) \qquad n \to \infty$$

Comment: I would say that equivalent was obtained through the generalized Stirling formula for the $\Gamma$ function, as pointed to by Yemon Choi.

Comment: That seems to be a reasonably likely explanation.  I just Googled for Pochhammer asymptotic, and didn't bother to think too much.